# Mysql connector .net for mac

Tags: c#, mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I'm a mac user and I have a project where I have to use C# and run queries where the data is stored in MySQL workbench. My friends who have windows told me that i should download mysql connector .net in order to establish the connection. But I can't seem to find one to download for mac. Is it possible to find one ? and should I do additional stuff to make the connection work? Thank you

Comment: Are you using .Net Core? Mono? What platform are you working?

Comment: I've downloaded the new visual studio for mac in order to write c#

Comment: Ok, maybe you have to target the code to run over the .Net Core and define the right provider. Maybe this link can help you: https://insidemysql.com/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-and-mysql-connectornet/

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to this site:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.10.html
```

Then choose the following:
[image]

Comment: I did download this one to try it but didn't know what to do afterwords. should i include a library or something in my c# code?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do if you are not using visual studio or vscode. If you are using one of those then follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163489/how-to-install-mysql-connector-for-net-c-sharp-on-mac