# How to install MySQL Connector for .NET C# on mac?

Tags: mysql-connector, visual-studio-mac

How to install MySQL Connector on a Mac and communicate and retrieve information from the database?
When I install Connector not **macOS** option (remember that I want to install **MySQL Connector for .NET**)
I expect this to be very simple but I can't find how to do it because I'm fairly new to Visual Studio for Mac ecosystem.

Comment: Please share more details of what you have tried so far. Then it would be easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Project -> Manage NuGet Package -> Search for Mysql -> Install it -> Done

Comment: I was using vscode so I needed to first install the nuget package manager: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675162/install-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-code/47856617    Then I had to instal `mysql.data` (I think it was the first option). Then vscode asked me to restore the project, and finally the linking was all set (imports recognized in the code).